# Stop toggle if already active JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle class between Siblings, but if one of them already have the calss added to him I want that it cant be changed.

Example: (if you click on one div that already open, it close. I need that if one div open you cant close it, only clicking on another div close the first one and open the new one) help ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sfb2').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('sfb-active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('sfb-active');
 });
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
}
.sfb1 {
 width: 99.8%;
 height: 400px;
}
.sfb2 {
 flex: 1;
 margin: 0px 6px;
 transition: flex .4s cubic-bezier(0.61,-0.19,0.7,-0.11);
 background-size: 1200px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.sfb-active {
 flex: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sfb1 flex center">
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i1 sfb-active">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i2">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i3">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i4">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i5">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the element has the class or no, if not, then do your code.
`!$(this).hasClass('sfb-active'){...}`

here, the `this` context points to the clicked element itself

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sfb2').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("sfb-active")){
      $(this).toggleClass('sfb-active');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('sfb-active');
    }
 });
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
}
.sfb1 {
 width: 99.8%;
 height: 400px;
}
.sfb2 {
 flex: 1;
 margin: 0px 6px;
 transition: flex .4s cubic-bezier(0.61,-0.19,0.7,-0.11);
 background-size: 1200px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.sfb-active {
 flex: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sfb1 flex center">
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i1 sfb-active">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i2">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i3">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i4">

  </div>
  <div class="sfb2 sfb-i5">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element has the class `sfb-active` before adding it:

```
$('.sfb2').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('sfb-active')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('sfb-active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('sfb-active');
    }
});
```